# How to bring heavy traffic to mysql database in my local machine?

Tags: mysql, performance, load-testing

Is there a way to bring heavy traffic(very frequent reads and writes) to mysql database in my local machine? Are there any tools available for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [mysqlslap](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlslap.html).